# Error while saving Random Forest Model in spark cluster scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm getting the following the `error` while saving a random forest model to disk. 
spark cluster configuration- 
spark-package - `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6`
mode - Standalone

I'm running spark by copying the same data in every slave machine

`command - localModel.save(SlapSparkContext.get(), path)`
model has been trained and it is predicting properly for test data

`error trace`

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.mergeFooters(ParquetFileWriter.java:456)
>       at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.writeMetadataFile(ParquetFileWriter.java:420)
>       at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.writeMetaDataFile(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:58)
>       at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:230)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:329)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.TreeEnsembleModel$SaveLoadV1_0$.save(treeEnsembleModels.scala:453)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel.save(treeEnsembleModels.scala:65)

Comment: Do you have the same error if you replace localModel.save(...) by localModel.count ?

Comment: eliasah -  Im unable to find any method name count. Im using spark-mllib_2.10 -version 1.6

Comment: then perform a count on the data your feed for the RF algorithm before running the algorithm

Comment: It is returning proper counts of the RDD it does not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when you are trying to save an *Empty* DataFrame. Check if the steps before this line of code are filtering/reducing your records.